# How do I re-render a list of components in React JS when the props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I hope you all are doing well. I have this problem where components inside a list are not re-rendering when their props change.

```
setTestFs([...testFs, <TestFunction t={test}/>])
```

This is the line used to assign a component to the list. Each component uses test as its 't' property.

```
function RenderTestFunctions({ts}) {
    return (
        ts.map((e, index) => {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    {e}
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
}

function TestFunction({t}) {
    console.log('just rendered + ' + t)

    return (
        <h1>{t}</h1>
    )
}
```

The RenderTestFunctions renders all of the TestFunction components.

For some reason whenever I update the test value, none of the components re-render, even though the RenderTestFunctions does render. Does anyone know how I can re-render all components in a list when a prop changes?

*please ask if you need any clarification. thank you for taking the time to look at this question!*

Comment: Where/when/how are you updating the `test` value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use useEffect hook whose main purpose is to solve and perform an action when he notices any change in that. You can useEffect like-

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (t !== null || undefined || "") {
    TestFunction({t})
  }
}, [testFs,test])
```

In use Effect, an array helps to trigger that particular function. while inside the arrow function you can create your own function. If you still facing just lemme know, and I will help you more.
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your reply! useEffect turned out to be very helpful in this situation; however, I am still trying to re-render all of the components in the list. I am calling the RenderTestFunctions component inside of the useEffect when test changes, but the TestFunction component is not being rendered.

Comment: Alright I think I figured it out. What I did, is instead of storing all the components in a list, I rendered them inside of the mapping function. Im a novice react user, but somehow (even though the mapping re-rendered) the states were able to retain their info. I want to see if this continues to work before posting it as an answer.